# Programmatically change linked contacts array in ABAddressBook, ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, contacts, abaddressbook

Can one programmatically add/remove the contacts inside the CFArray returned by **ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople**, thus, effectively, linking and un-linking different records of contacts from various sources to show as "unified" in the iOs phone book?

Comment: If you have the same question about the more recent CNContact API, you can check out this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944065/programmatically-link-cncontacts/66371184

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've been able to determine, there is no public API exposed for linking or unlinking contacts, at least in the iOS 6 SDK. However, it does appear that you can create links between contacts by calling the undocumented, private function `bool ABPersonLinkPerson(ABRecordRef from, ABRecordRef to)`. That signature may not be exactly right--I haven't tested this too thoroughly.

Your app is of course unlikely to be approved if you make use of private APIs, but if you're trying to, say, make a fake address book for the sake of unit testing and you want some linked contacts in that, this could be useful.