# Trigger Auto-Linking of Contacts in iOS

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I am making an applications that creates contacts in the iPhones address book. This sometimes leads to duplicate entries when adding contacts to many sources (i.e. exchange, CardDAV, Local, etc.)

I need to be able to link these duplicate contacts in the address book. I have found that this is not possible for any two arbitrary contacts [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186513/programmaticly-change-linked-contacts-array-in-abaddressbook-abpersoncopyarrayo).

However, all i need is for the "auto-linking" that occurs when a new source is enabled on the phone to be triggered. This auto-linking causes all similar contacts to be linked together automatically, which is exactly what i want.

The only solution i can find is to ask the user to disable/enable their sources, but it would be much smoother if this could be triggered automatically.

Anybody have an idea how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but related to your question...  This answer says that automatic linking can occur between contacts with the same name if they are from different accounts:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523203/3791490