# Programmatically Link CNContacts

Tags: ios, contacts, ios9

In my app, I want to create a new contact. If a contact with the same name already exists, I want to link the new contact to the old one.

I have looked into the CNContact and CNContactStore references, and don't see any way to link contacts. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Did you find a way to merge two contacts other than creating a new `CNMutableContact` and manually merging the attributes omitting the duplicates? If you were able to merge two contacts can you tell how?

Comment: @Adeel I have not found a solution, but I haven't looked for a while either.

Comment: It's been over 8 years since this was asked. Is there any improvement in this area?

Answer (score 2):

In IOS9 contacts in different accounts that represent the same person may be automatically linked together.

To achieve this you should make sure that the name of your newly inserted contact matches the name of the contact you would like to unify with.

The documentation linked below gives the example of "John Appleseed" on iCloud and Facebook.

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html

Comment: I don't see the example. Is that an old link?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this for sure, but I suspect that iOS only links across different sources. And if you create both contacts in the same address book they wont be linked.

There is very little support for this area in the Contacts library. You can detect if a contact is unified and linked to another specific contact using CNContact.isUnifiedWithContact(withIdentifier:), and you can decide whether you are going to return unified contacts or not.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to merge a contact with the already present contact in contact store.Just an FYI that unique values like given name family name will be replaced and arrays such as numbers, emails, addresses will be appended with the existing values. Cheers!!

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let identifier = contact.identifier
    updateContact(contactIdentifier: identifier)
}

func updateContact(contactIdentifier: String){

    let keysToFetch = [CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    do {
        let contactToUpdate =  try contactStore.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: contactIdentifier, keysToFetch: keysToFetch).mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
        if contactToUpdate.familyName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
            contactToUpdate.familyName = "your value"
        }
        if contactToUpdate.givenName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
            contactToUpdate.givenName = "your value"
        }
        if contactToUpdate.organizationName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
            contactToUpdate.organizationName = "your value"
        }
        if contactToUpdate.jobTitle.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
            contactToUpdate.jobTitle = "your value"
        }
  // here the contact used below is the one that you want to merge with 
     an existing one.

        for i in contact.phoneNumbers {
            contactToUpdate.phoneNumbers.append(i)
        }
        for i in contact.emailAddresses {
            contactToUpdate.emailAddresses.append(i)
        }
        for i in contact.postalAddresses {
            contactToUpdate.postalAddresses.append(i)
        }
        let contactsViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contactToUpdate)
        contactsViewController.delegate = self
        contactsViewController.title = "Edit contact"
        contactsViewController.contactStore = contactStore
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactsViewController)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that this code combines information from two contacts into a single contact.  However, the original question was asking about linking two contacts together.  Linking does not modify either contact, but instead creates a "unified" contact that displays information from both of the linked contacts.  For more info, see the "Unified Contacts" section on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts#1773387

Answer (score 0):

The CNContact framework has many issues, one of which is the documentation but when you create a contact in multiple containers, each will have their own identifier (which can change almost as soon as created, ex Gmail containers). They should be automatically linked through a Unified Contact. However I have noticed that if the contact only has a given name (no family name) the contacts won't be linked. I am not sure what matching key Apple is using to create the Unified Contact, but it seems to be the combination of the given and family names assuming they are not duplicated.
I didn't find any way to programmatically link the contacts together.